# Naming convention for Delphi Interface Units

Tags: delphi, interface, naming-conventions

Is there a widely used naming convention for Delphi units that contain only interface definitions?

**I'm asking specifically if anything exists that has become a widespread convention in the Delphi community. I am *not* asking for your opinion on what is a good convention, or even necessarily what you use personally. Your answer needs to demonstrate that what you describe is a widespread convention by saying where you've seen it used.**

To illustrate the question more clearly I'll describe my organisation's homegrown convention and why I'm not satisfied with it: If a class is called `TFoo`, then its unit would be called `uFoo`. An interface implemented by `TFoo` would probably be called `IFoo`, but obviously I can't save this unit as `iFoo` because the interface already has that name.

In other words, I'm trying to complete this grid:

```
+--------+---------------+---------------+
!        !  Class        !  Interface    !
+--------+---------------+---------------+
!        !               !               !
! Name   !  TFoo         !  IFoo         !
!        !               !               !
+--------+---------------+---------------+
!        !               !               !
! File   !  uFoo.pas     !  ????.pas     !
!        !               !               !
+--------+---------------+---------------+
```

---

Updated on 19 March 2014 to make it clearer that I'm looking for fact-based (not opinion-based) answers.

Comment: I use uIFoo.pas convention. e.g. for IModalForm interface, uIModalForm, etc.

Comment: I don't think it's that simple. You have single classes and interfaces in all your units? Really? Your classes never implement more than one interface? Really? You never have an interface implemented by more than one class? Really?

Comment: There are litterally as many conventions as there are Delphi developers. I would consider that modern Delphi versions support pseudo-namespacing using dot notation on unit names. Like System.Classes, System.SysUtils. Etc. Personally I Name all my units according to this scheme CompanyName.ProductName.Topic.Subtopic.

Comment: My own convention is: `F` prefix for Forms, `D` for DataModules, `U` for utility units, `Aw` for own framework/package units. Then the name which describes the name of the Form or the DataModule, or a group name to which utilities/components/controls belong.

Comment: I've edited the question in the hope that it can be reopened.

Comment: @David No, but I do have a fair number of instances of a class that implements one interface with the interface stored in a separate unit. There are lots of reasons for doing this. (But I agree with you that 'never' is rarely/never(?) an appropriate rule.)

Comment: You had to wait four people to post their opinions/their own conventions to tell that you're not interested in any?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Be fair, please. 1) The original question asked people to say where they've seen the convention used; I was not just asking for opinions (notwithstanding that people love giving them). 2) It was in response to the question being put on hold that I clarified it. 3) Three of the four responses were made outside work hours here in the UK.

Comment: @Ian - To be accurate the original question asked where they've seen it *or if it's their own*. All of the answers satisfied that query.

Comment: @Ian - Looking at the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22486130/revisions), your edit (your first edit AMOF) involving fact-based answers is stamped: 2014-03-19 08:25:59. All of the four answers are dated 2014-03-18. Smaller date is earlier. And no, nowhere I've said improving the question is wrong.

Comment: Some people here tend to nitpick ALOT. Whats wrong about asking how other people name their interfaces? Personally, I like the question and it improved my skills, I switched from uI* to ProjectName.Bla.Bla naming convention, after I read Anders comment.

Comment: @Marko - If you imply me as one of some people I suggest you to read my comment again. If that's the case in fact, you should have done that already.

Comment: I dont imply to anyone specifically. Just saw this as valid question that got downvoted to oblivion and put on hold, and thats why I felt the need to write something. This should be place where people can exchange their experiences, not to wait for opportunity to downvote/close any question that is even slightly off the rules. Thats how I see SO atleast. But obviously I'm in minority here.

Comment: @Ian - I don't understand what you're asking. You seem to believe that I imply something, I don't. I've made that clear. What I said is, you could have told what you don't want earlier. This is what I said in my first comment. Now I'm back at square one..

Comment: @Ian - The revision history does not show what you are telling.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz The revision history is incomplete. I don't know why it doesn't show all of my edits from yesterday.

Comment: @Ian - no ned to be dramatic about it, just a little criticising :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use Foo_Intf for the file name. I have seen RemObjects use it when it automatically generates units. I think the programmers I worked with picked it up from RO and I picked it up from them. It makes sense to me since it makes finding the interfaces easy.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `uFooAPI.pas` for the unit declaring the abstract interface. It's my own convention.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no naming convention for the units.

But lets have a look what we are trying to do with the interfaces.

If we have an interface `IFoo` we will talk to something that behaves like `Foo` through an interface. Every class that implements `IFoo` is not `Foo` but a *behaves like Foo*.

So to me if there is one unit only for `IFoo` I would name this unit `Foo`.

```
unit Foo;

interface

type
  IFoo = interface
    ['{GUID}']
    procedure Bar;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

Maybe there is a starting `IFoo` implementing class

```
unit AbstractFoo;

interface

uses Foo;

type
  TAbstractFoo = class abstract( TInterfacedObject, IFoo )
  public
    procedure Bar; virtual; abstract;
  end;

interface

end.
```

or a class consuming `IFoo`

```
unit FooUser;

interface

uses Foo;

type
  TFooUser = class
  public
    procedure Consume( Foo : IFoo );
  end;

implementation

procedure TFooUser.Consume( Foo : IFoo );
begin
  Foo.Bar;
end;

end.
```

Most the times we use only the interface and not one of the implementing classes and that leads me again to name the interface declaration unit `Foo`.

Comment: I thought someone might give an answer like this. Yes, I agree totally with the sentiment. But it isn't always the case that there is more than one class that implements the interface. Sometimes we create an interface for a specific class (rather than the other way around). This is the point at which my existing naming convention falls over.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many classes implements the interface. But I know what is your case. Often there is a class and at a time you declare an interface for that. I always sigh when I reach that point, because I did not put enough effort into my plan and now I have to refactor that :o)

Answer (score 0):

```
Type of unit           prefix
general unit           u_
interface declaration  i_
form                   w_
data module            d_
frame                  wf_
```

(That's our internal convention, I don't know whether anybody else uses it. I brought this convention to my current employer from another company that got bought by some other company, but I don't think they still use Delphi. If they do, they might still use it.)